# what is the difference between x[1,2] and x[1][2] in hierarchy indexing for series in python?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, hierarchy

I have a series

```
x=pd.Series(np.random.random(16),index=[[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d']])
```

that looks like this:

```
1  a   -0.068167
   b   -1.036551
   c   -0.246619
   d    1.318381
2  a   -0.119061
   b    0.249653
   c    0.819153
   d    1.334510
3  a    0.029305
   b   -0.879798
   c    1.081574
   d   -1.590322
4  a    0.620149
   b   -2.197523
   c    0.927573
   d   -0.274370
dtype: float64
```

What is the difference between x[1,'a'] and x[1]['a']. It gives me the same answer. I am confused as to what the difference internally means? When should I use the above two indexes?

Comment: What library provides this `Series` object?

Comment: The Pandas library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This explanation is from the [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html), however I believe a similar thing is happening in pandas (which uses numpy inside, using "indexers" to provide a mapping between a (possibly) named index and the underlying integer-based index).

> So note that x[0,2] = x[0][2] though the second case is less efficient as a new temporary array is created after the first index that is subsequently indexed by 2.

Here are the timings for your series; the first method is around 30 times faster:

```
In [79]: %timeit x[1, 'a']
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.46 µs per loop

In [80]: %timeit x[1]['a']
1000 loops, best of 3: 274 µs per loop
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with numpy and is pandas specific as this is a MultiIndex; please update the answer so as not to misinform

Comment: @jeff i wouldn't say it has **nothing** to do with numpy ?!

Comment: With NumPy arrays, `x[1]` would be a view, and the performance difference would be a lot lower. I think a proper answer to this question requires more Pandas-specific insight into what the indexing does.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `x[1, 'a']`, pandas is taking the `1, 'a'` as a tuple `(1, 'a')` and returning the series value that corresponds to the `(1, 'a')` index label.

In the case of `x[1]['a']`, pandas is figuring out that what you passed within `[]` is not a tuple in which it can reference it's index with and so finally figures that it may be a reference to an element of the first level.  `x[1]` then returns a cross section of `x` on which we attempt to slice again with `['a']`.